# SELECT query with prepare and placeholder for string

Tags: select, wpdb

I am trying to learn how to do a simple Select query using $wpdb-prepare.

I am checking wether an email submitted by the user is already available in the database.

There has to be something wrong with the syntax because the string placeholder is undefined, according to PHPstorm.

```
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'members';
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE email = $s", $mail);
$result = $sql->get_results($sql);
```

What would the correct syntax be?

Comment: Placeholder should be `%s` and not `$s`. Latter is a variable, not a placeholder, that is why you get the undefined notice

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `$wpdb` as global.

Try this code.

```
global $wpdb;

$mail = $_POST['email'];

$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'members';

$result = $sql->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE email = %s", $mail);
```

Comment: I had "global $wpdb;" at the top, just forgot to include it. But the problem was with $s (should be %s)